# Would it be possible to create a working computer interface in threejs

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Would it be possible to create a window in threejs that would allow me to use normal desktop applications (code editors, etc) from inside of the scene?

Note: I'm doing this inside of a custom application, or a node-webkit application, so there are no restrictions on file usage

Answer (score 0):

From within the browser? No. You are restricted to what HTML5 DOM APIs offer you, which is that they don't have access to the desktop directly. (You can make a plugin to do this using a plugin API for browsers but that's still quite involved.)

Comment: What if I were to run it in a node-webkit application, meaning I have no file restrictions. Is it fundamentally possible to pipe my desktop inside of a threejs scene?

Comment: Possibly, but not using ThreeJS only. Assuming you want full control, you'd need to probably attempt at using a remote desktop protocol (recommend searching for a lib for this in node). You don't have access to manipulate the desktop directly even as a user application.

Comment: Do you think it might be possible to pipe full applications, but not the desktop itself?